# Missing <missing> Image Layer ID for subsequent child layers - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build and docker history <image id>

Tags: docker, image, caching, containers, docker-buildkit

**Docker version 19.03.12**, build 48a66213fe

**OS**: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)

**Please See**: Dockerfile have minimal steps and it builds successfully.

To create docker image, I ran (*this command will capture stdout/stderr in a .log file*):

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build \
                         --network=host \
                         -t project-opensuse-docker-image:15.2 . \
                         |& tee -a /tmp/project-opensuse-docker-image.log
```

When I use `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` during `docker build .......` command, it makes **Image ID** of the subsequent image layers listed as **`<missing>`**; If I re-run docker build again as soon as the first run completes successfully, it is **NOT** able to use any layer cache concept to go/build fast **even though** there's **no change done to  Dockerfile or any folder/file on the file system** (i.e if used during COPY / ADD etc steps).

**It builds everytime from scratch** and I think, the reason is because there's NO valid IMAGE ID for those subsequent layers under the **final** Image ID: `a07eebd0a9ba`.

See Image ID in `docker history <image>` output showing  for subsequent layer's IDs.

**WHY** am I getting  under **Image ID** for these layers?

```
​    
[gigauser@rh79maipo_machine opensuse-x]$ sudo docker history a07eebd0a9ba
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                              SIZE                COMMENT
a07eebd0a9ba        3 hours ago         CMD ["ls -l"]                                           0B                  buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           3 hours ago         WORKDIR /home/nonroot_user                              0B                  buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           3 hours ago         VOLUME [/home/nonroot_user/git]                         0B                  buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           3 hours ago         RUN /bin/sh -c ls -l /home/nonroot_user /home/rayd…     174MB               buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           3 hours ago         COPY ./boost_1_68_0.tar.gz /home/nonroot_user/tool…     109MB               buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           3 hours ago         RUN /bin/sh -c ls -l /home/nonroot_user /home/rayd…     253MB               buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           3 hours ago         COPY ./wxWidgets-3.1.3.tar.bz2 /home/nonroot_user/…     21.3MB              buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           3 hours ago         RUN /bin/sh -c echo -e "\n-- Installing Zypper…         1.71GB              buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           26 hours ago        RUN /bin/sh -c useradd     -r     -m     -l …           953kB               buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           26 hours ago        COPY ./CompanyCertBundle/PEM/*.cer /usr/sha…            34.7kB              buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           26 hours ago        ENV http_proxy=http://company.proxy.com:80/ …           0B                  buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           26 hours ago        LABEL Project=aPROJECT IM CentOS_Version=CentOS…        0B                  buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           4 weeks ago         KIWI 9.23.20                                            109MB
[gigauser@rh79maipo_machine opensuse-x]$
```